# Postfix limit rcpt to

Tags: postfix

In Postfix, I want to limit the domains for RCPT TO, for example I only want @google.com and @yahoo.com, but not everything else. Is this possible?

I was able to limit the "mail from:" using smtpd_sender_restrictions regexp. I did try using the regexp in smtpd_recipient_restrictions but no success. I wondering if it has something related to testing with telnet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with [postfix restriction classes](http://www.postfix.org/RESTRICTION_CLASS_README.html), one under `smtp_sender_restrictions` like so:

> check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/restricted_senders

in restricted senders add the from domain matches.

> your.domain     google_only
>   second.domain     google_only

Then in `smtpd_restriction_classes` add a line like this:

> smtpd_restriction_classes = google_only
>   google_only = check_recipient_access hash:/etc/postfix/google_only, reject

with these sort of lines in google only

> yahoo.com  OK
>   google.com  OK

This way you can also create accounts which can send anywhere. This only restricts what people can send through your server, they can use some other mail relay or use a from address that isn't native to your server (you could lock that down with SASL and [smtp_sender_login_maps](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_sender_login_maps) though).

Comment: Don't forget to run `postmap /etc/postfix/restricted_senders` and `postmap /etc/postfix/google_only` to build the hash files from your plaintext files.

Comment: I cannot vote because of my low reputation, the solution worked well. thank you!